# send-mailmessage remove corporate default signature

Tags: powershell

When I do this:

```
Send-MailMessage -To 'user@domain.com' -From 'test@domain.com' -Subject 'testsubject' -Body 'testbody' -SmtpServer 'smtp.domain.com'
```

I get the email with no signature (as desired).

However, when i do this:

```
Send-MailMessage -To '1234567890@vtext.com' -From 'test@domain.com' -Subject 'testsubject' -Body 'testbody' -SmtpServer 'smtp.domain.com'
```

I get the message on my phone with from, subject, and body, but at the end of the message there is a line of `_` followed by what appears to be a corporate standard email signature.

Is there any way to prevent that from being included in the message?

Or, is there any way to change the corporate email signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a transport rule on the server. You can't control what the smtp does to your mail.

The only thing I could think of is to try and sign it using s/mime. Hopefully the rule on the smtp ignores signed mails to avoid breaking them (integrity-signature not matching the content), It's worth a try.

I would contact the administrators and ask for that particular mailaddress to be excluded from the rule.

Comment: Do you have a link for the steps to review/update the current transport rules?

Comment: It would depend on the mail server and version. Here's instruction for adding in exchange 2013 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600323(v=exchg.150).aspx